# Apache server sub directory pages are not showing

Tags: php, apache, webserver, lamp

I am using `LAMP` on my ubuntu 12.04 system. When I browse any sub directory or sub page which is located inside my /var/www/ folder it is showing like

```
Not Found
The requested URL /directory/subdirectory/filename was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

But the file is already present in that sub directory. So can someone kindly tell me why I am getting this error? Any help and suggestions will behighly appreciable. Thanks

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file is like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have a look at the Apache error log.

Comment: You posted your sites-available/default file. Whats about the sites-enabled/... ? Have you already enabled your site using a2ensite?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of access permission on the sub folder, try

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/subfolder 
Or 
chmod -R 775 /var/www/subfolder
```

as per your folder structure